# Get Links in class with html agility pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

There are a bunch of tr's with the class alt. I want to get all the links (or the first of last) yet i cant figure out how with html agility pack.

I tried variants of a but i only get all the links or none. It doesnt seem to only get the one in the node which makes no sense since i am writing n.SelectNodes

```
html.LoadHtml(page);
var nS = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='alt']");
foreach (var n in nS)
{
  var aS = n.SelectNodes("a");
  ...
}
```

Comment: can you show a snippet of the html you are trying to parse?  I'm not entirely clear on what you are trying to do

Comment: @jaltiere: He wants the CSS selector `tr.alt a`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
var links = html.DocumentNode
           .Descendants("tr")
           .Where(tr => tr.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Contains("alt"))
           .SelectMany(tr => tr.Descendants("a"))
           .ToArray();
```

Note that this will also match `<tr class="Malto">`; you may want to replace the `Contains` call with a regex.

You could also use [Fizzler](http://code.google.com/p/fizzler/):

```
html.DocumentNode.QuerySelectorAll("tr.alt a");
```

Note that both methods will also return anchors that aren't links.

Answer (score 11):

Why not select all links in single query:

```
html.LoadHtml(page);
var nS = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='alt']//a");
foreach(HtmlNode linkNode in nS)
{
//do something
}
```

It's valid for html:

```
<table>
<tr class = "alt">
<td><'a href="link.html">Some Link</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```